# How can I pass props into stackNavigator in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I made a login controller Component then I passed my stackNavigator into it, my problem is that I should pass jwt token into the screens but I can't access the "this.state.jwt"

I know there are familiar questions but I just couldn't wrap my head around the answers.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      jwt: '',
      loading: true
    }

    this.newJWT = this.newJWT.bind(this);
    this.deleteJWT = deviceStorage.deleteJWT.bind(this);
    this.loadJWT = deviceStorage.loadJWT.bind(this);
    this.loadJWT();
  }

  newJWT(jwt){
    this.setState({
      jwt: jwt
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      this.deleteJWT()
      return (
        <Loading size={'large'} />
       );
    } else if (!this.state.jwt) {
      return (
        <Auth newJWT={this.newJWT} />
      );
    } else if (this.state.jwt) {
      return (
        <RootNav screenProps={this.state.jwt} />
      );
    }
  }
}

const BottomNaviagtor = createBottomTabNavigator ({

  Home: Home,
  Top: Top,
  Following: {screen: Following},
  LikeD: {screen:Liked}
})

const RootNav = createAppContainer(BottomNaviagtor)
```

Somehow I should do this: Home jwt={this.state.jw} and do this for all others bottomNavigator screens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry not enough points to comment, i see your are passing it as a screenProp, if you modify your screenProps to

> screenProps={{
>                   jwt: this.state.jwt}}

do you have access in your screens doing this.props.screenProps.jwt?

Comment: Thank you I changed it to this.props.screenProps.jwt and it works. Cheers!